ROS2.Jazzy Python Custom Messages
The official Python tutorial only uses a String type for the message examples. I want something more complex, like LaserScan. I cannot tell if this is possible for a pure Python project.
I just want to publish Lidar data that I've analyzed down to {Angle, Range} for ranges under .2 meters. Instead I've been fighting for msg recognition for hours.
I asked chatGPT and Claude and they both give me something like I've pasted below but their output does not create usable msgs. The msg types do not resolve and nothing I've tried gets around it.
e.g. An error is noted but doesn't say why. No package is emitted.

colcon build
1 package had stderr output: custom_msgs_demo

When I load the workspace into vscode, it notes that the msg folder is not resolved:
from custom_msgs_demo.msg import SensorData, SensorArray

-->
custom_msgs_demo.msg could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)
In torturous LLM sessions, the models tend to equivocate on whether CMakeLists.txt and ament_cmake or ament_python are necessary for Python. Here in stackexchange, I found oblique ideas that msgs have to be in a different project due to CMakeLists requirements. However, it points to a C++ example. Are complex message types possible in pure Python?
No, I have not forgotten to source install/source.bash
Directory structure:

custom_msgs_demo/
├── custom_msgs_demo/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── publisher_node.py
│   └── subscriber_node.py
├── msg/
│   ├── SensorData.msg
│   └── SensorArray.msg
├── package.xml
├── setup.py
├── setup.cfg
└── resource/
    └── custom_msgs_demo

# File: msg/SensorData.msg
# Individual sensor reading with multiple fields
float32 distance      # Distance measurement in meters
float32 angle        # Angle of the measurement in radians
string  sensor_id    # Unique identifier for the sensor
bool    is_valid     # Validity flag for the measurement

# File: msg/SensorArray.msg
# Array of sensor readings with timestamp
builtin_interfaces/Time timestamp    # When the readings were taken
SensorData[] readings               # Array of sensor readings
string frame_id                     # Reference frame for these measurements

# File: package.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematype="xsd"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>custom_msgs_demo</name>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <description>Demo package for custom messages in ROS 2 Python</description>
  <maintainer email="user@todo.todo">user</maintainer>
  <license>Apache License 2.0</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_python</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>
  
  <depend>rclpy</depend>
  <depend>std_msgs</depend>
  <depend>builtin_interfaces</depend>
  
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

# File: setup.py
from setuptools import setup
import os
from glob import glob

package_name = 'custom_msgs_demo'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'msg'), glob('msg/*.msg')),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='user',
    maintainer_email='user@todo.todo',
    description='Demo package for custom messages in ROS 2 Python',
    license='Apache License 2.0',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'publisher = custom_msgs_demo.publisher_node:main',
            'subscriber = custom_msgs_demo.subscriber_node:main',
        ],
    },
)

# File: custom_msgs_demo/publisher_node.py
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from custom_msgs_demo.msg import SensorData, SensorArray
from builtin_interfaces.msg import Time
import math
import random

class SensorPublisher(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('sensor_publisher')
        # Create publisher for sensor array
        self.publisher = self.create_publisher(SensorArray, 'sensor_data', 10)
        # Create timer for periodic publishing
        self.timer = self.create_timer(1.0, self.publish_data)  # 1 Hz
        self.get_logger().info('Sensor publisher node initialized')

    def publish_data(self):
        # Create message instance
        msg = SensorArray()
        msg.frame_id = "sensor_array_1"
        
        # Get current time
        now = self.get_clock().now()
        msg.timestamp = Time(sec=now.seconds_nanoseconds()[0],
                           nanosec=now.seconds_nanoseconds()[1])

        # Generate some simulated sensor readings
        for i in range(3):  # Generate 3 readings
            reading = SensorData()
            reading.distance = random.uniform(0.1, 5.0)  # Random distance 0.1-5.0m
            reading.angle = random.uniform(-math.pi/2, math.pi/2)  # Random angle
            reading.sensor_id = f"sensor_{i}"
            reading.is_valid = random.random() > 0.1  # 90% valid readings
            msg.readings.append(reading)

        # Publish the message
        self.publisher.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info(
            f'Published {len(msg.readings)} sensor readings')

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    publisher = SensorPublisher()
    
    try:
        rclpy.spin(publisher)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        publisher.destroy_node()
        rclpy.shutdown()

# File: custom_msgs_demo/subscriber_node.py
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from custom_msgs_demo.msg import SensorArray

class SensorSubscriber(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('sensor_subscriber')
        # Create subscription
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            SensorArray,
            'sensor_data',
            self.listener_callback,
            10)
        self.get_logger().info('Sensor subscriber node initialized')

    def listener_callback(self, msg):
        # Process received message
        self.get_logger().info(f'Received sensor data from frame: {msg.frame_id}')
        self.get_logger().info(f'Timestamp: {msg.timestamp.sec}.{msg.timestamp.nanosec}')
        
        # Process each sensor reading
        for i, reading in enumerate(msg.readings):
            if reading.is_valid:
                self.get_logger().info(
                    f'Reading {i} from {reading.sensor_id}: '
                    f'distance={reading.distance:.2f}m, '
                    f'angle={reading.angle:.2f}rad')

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    subscriber = SensorSubscriber()
    
    try:
        rclpy.spin(subscriber)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        subscriber.destroy_node()
        rclpy.shutdown()



Are complex message types possible in pure Python?

No.
From the official tutorial pages
https://docs.ros.org/en/jazzy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html#create-a-new-package

Note that it is, and can only be, a CMake package, but this doesn’t restrict in which type of packages you can use your messages and services. You can create your own custom interfaces in a CMake package, and then use it in a C++ or Python node, which will be covered in the last section.

https://docs.ros.org/en/jazzy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html#cmakelists-txt

To convert the interfaces you defined into language-specific code (like C++ and Python) so that they can be used in those languages, add the following lines to CMakeLists.txt ...

find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators 
REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/Num.msg"
  "msg/Sphere.msg"
  "srv/AddThreeInts.srv"
  DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs # Add packages 
that above messages depend on, in this case 
geometry_msgs for Sphere.msg
)


Here in stackexchange, I found oblique ideas that msgs have to be in a different project due to CMakeLists requirements. However, it points to a C++ example.

Yes, there's some obscure way to make it work in the same package and I've done it before, but I think this is considered an antipattern in ROS 2 anyway. I don't recall how to make it work. Messages defined in a separate interface package are preferred and straightforward.

Thank you, I got it working!!!
